# Process next iteration of loop while 'await'ing

Tags: python, asynchronous

I'm working on figuring out the new async keywords added in Python 3.5+ and I had a problem I am trying to solve using async. Here's a simple example:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession
session = ClientSession()
for x in data:
  # x=LOTS OF POST DATA
  async with session.post("my-url.com", data=x) as response:
    # START THE NEXT ITERATION OF THE LOOP NOW
    rep = await response.read()
    ...
    # DO SOME WORK WITH THE RESPONSE
```

The problem here is instead of moving to the next iteration, it will halt the thread.

I know of ways to run through all the URLs at once and put them into futures for looping through all of them later for post processing, however I want to do work on the response after it's ready, not all at once later on.

Is there anyway to prevent wasted time when it is waiting for the response to be ready? Ideally while it's waiting for the network IO I would want the script to start queuing up some more responses to run. Since the data being posted takes awhile to upload.

If anything is unclear please let me know and I'll do my best to answer. Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that to do what you want, the body of the loop (the `async with` line and the rest) should be in a separate coroutine that you schedule in the loop, rather than running it directly.

Comment: @Blckknght could you help with an example of what you mean? You mean a separate async def? From what I tried that still halts the loop

Comment: I'm not very experienced with asynchronous code, so I'm not sure I know how to do it right. But the main trick is to schedule the factored out coroutine with your event loop rather than directly `await`ing it. Try something like `asyncio.ensure_future(post_data_and_handle_response(x))`, or maybe something using `asyncio.gather` with a comprehension to schedule all the coroutines for all your `x` values at once.